# How to setup LSTM problem when using multiple time series inputs?

Tags: time-series, lstm

**Problem:**
Suppose I have 50 time series which I want to train on. For each series, given the last say 4 samples, I would like to predict the next value.

Suppose each series is 100 samples. I break each series to 25 sub-samples. So in total, I have 100 * 25 = 2500 sub-samples.

The LSTM input is 3 dimensional input. One for sequence length (4 in this case), one for batch, and one for number of features (1 in this case).

How do I feed the input? This requirement suggests that I have to stack all my sub-samples together, and form the input set as the sub-samples.

If I do that, it would imply that I can feed the input randomly to the network.

If I do that, it would imply that the network is only affected by 4 inputs and any history before that is meaningless (because I may feed the input of 4 samples randomly)

Is this the correct method to setup the problem? Or do I have to batch each sample (4 sub-samples) together?